# Return function when true with a value

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where I need to return a value when the statement inside for loop is true.
As per the code below: I am returning false when the condition satisfied but I am not getting any value when the condition satisfied in the loop.

```
function isFeatureAllowed(data){
            _.each(user.restrictions.restrictedFeatures, function(restriction){
                if(restriction.name.indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
                    return false;
                }
            })
        }

console.log(isFeatureAllowed) should return true.
if(isFeatureAllowed){
   //do something
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `restrictedFeatures` is an array, you can use the `.every` function:

```
const isAllowed = feature =>
  restrictedFeatures.every(r => !r.name.includes(feature.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: The only good answer so far, but it might need some further explanations ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
function isFeatureAllowed(data){
            var value = true;
            _.each(user.restrictions.restrictedFeatures, function(restriction){
                if(restriction.name.indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
                    value = false;
                }
            })
            return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In lodash if you use `return false` then it will `break` the loop but do not return anything to your calling function. Thus to return the value you can take a temporary variable say, `flag` to store the value and return that before breaking the loop.

```js
var user = {
  restrictions : {
    restrictedFeatures: [
      {
        name: ['somename']
      }
    ]
  }
}
function isFeatureAllowed(data){
  let flag = true;
   _.each(user.restrictions.restrictedFeatures, function(restriction){
      if(restriction.name.indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
          flag = false;
          return false;
      }
  })
  return flag;
}

console.log(isFeatureAllowed('SOMENAME'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do in this way:

```
function isFeatureAllowed(data){
        _.each(user.restrictions.restrictedFeatures, function(restriction){
            if(restriction.name.indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
                return false;
            }
        })
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This will always return true.

Comment: @Ivar yes, using `return false` will break the loop but not return.